# JavaScript: Why This Code Doesn't Work?

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, text

I am trying to create an text encrypter, but when i entered this code, nothing happens. What is wrong with my code?

```
function Encrypt(txt) {
var chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v','w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}
for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    var chr = txt.charAt(i);
    var pos = chars.indexOf(chr);
    if (pos == chars.length) {
        pos = 0;
    }
    else {
        pos = pos++
    }
    txt.charAt(i) = chars[pos];
}
alert(txt);
}
```

Comment: `chars` should be an array (enclosed in [ ] ) .

Comment: Something happens: a syntax error.

Comment: If you're running this in a browser (the `alert` suggests you are), open your web console. It will show you an error. The web console, and the debugger built into your browser, are *invaluable tools* when doing browser-based development.

Answer (score 4):

You need

- array `[]` instead of object `{}`,
- some declared variables
- an empty result string `newText`, a string is read only with the [character access](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access)
- a valid check if the letter is not in the array
- increment `pos` without assignment.
- append the result string with the encoded character

```js
function Encrypt(txt) {
    var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
        i, newText = '', chr, pos;

    for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
        chr = txt[i];
        pos = chars.indexOf(chr);
        if (!~pos) {
            pos = 0;
        } else {
            pos++;
        }
        newText += chars[pos];
    }
    document.write(newText);
}

Encrypt('test');
```

Comment: Of course, `chars` could just be a string. Strings have `indexOf`, too.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i tend to keep the spirit of the source code. but you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is not an array, but object... and object has to have `"index" : "value"` structure.

Change this:

`var chars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v','w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}`

to this:

`var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v','w', 'x', 'y', 'z']`

Comment: That's *half* of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not considering the errors well described in the other answers, my proposal to encrypt a string is:

```js
function Encrypt(txt) {
  var chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v','w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
  var txtResult = txt.split('').map(function(val) {
    var pos = chars.indexOf(val);
    return chars[(pos == chars.length) ? 0 : (pos + 1)];
  }).join('');
  document.write(txtResult);
}
Encrypt('gaemaf');
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already updated my code, so it works just fine!